# How do I change out the underlying object inside a method call?

Tags: python, oop

I thought all function and method arguments in Python were passed by reference, leading me to believe that the following code would work:

```
class Insect:
    def status(self):
        print "i am a %s" % self

class Caterpillar(Insect):
        def grow_up(self):
                self = Butterfly() # replace myself with a new object
                return

class Butterfly(Insect):
        pass

my_obj = Caterpillar()
my_obj.status() # i am a <__main__.Caterpillar instance at 0x100494710>

# ok, time to grow up:
my_obj.grow_up()

my_obj.status() # want new Butterfly object, but it is still Caterpillar! :(
```

How do I go about changing the object itself within a method call?

-- EDIT:

So far, the responses have been:

1) Change self.__class__ to change the class associated with the current object.
2) "Don't hold it that way."

The original question: How do I make a *new* object that takes the place of the old one from within a method call defined on the old class?

I think the answer might actually be "you can't."

-- EDIT2:

Why is everyone deathly afraid of saying "It's not possible"?

Comment: For one thing: you should not think of passing things "by reference". What makes sense to think about when you code in Python is that you pass "objects" around. On the "arrival", objects are bound to a name (or even more names afterwards). Pointing the name to another,newly created object, does nothing to the original object.

Answer (score 3):

When you say `self = Butterfly()` all you're doing is changing what the variable `self` points to; you're not changing what self is, any more than:

```
x = 1
x = 2
```

... changes the number 1 to 2.

In general, when people need this, rather than change the type of the object (which many languages flat out forbid) people use a composition strategy:

```
class Lepidoptera(Insect):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stage = Caterpillar()

    def status(self):
        print 'I am a %s' % self.stage

    def grow_up(self):
        if self.stage.adult:
            raise TypeError('Already an adult')

        self.stage = Butterfly()
```

Comment: What I need is a method WITHIN the Caterpillar class that can change the object into a member of Butterfly.  The only way I've seen so far is to iterate over the attributes, back them up, change \_\_class__, empty \_\_dict__, then call \_\_init__ with whatever I need out of the backed-up attributes.  All of this seems really hacky to me, and I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: And we're saying, that's not the way object-oriented languages are designed.  Any solution is going to be hacky.  This suggests you might want to rethink your architecture.

Comment: That's a gross oversimplification that basically amounts to "Don't hold it that way."  Perl handles this sort of thing just fine.

Comment: Funny how Perl is so rarely cited for the elegance and power of its object semantics.

Comment: Not to turn this into a flame war, but all of CPAN stands in counter to your implication.

Answer (score 2):

`self.__class__ = Butterfly` may work, because it's rebinding a **qualified** name (which is a **completely** different thing from rebinding a **bare** name).

Rebinding a barename never has **any** effect on whatever object was previously bound to it (unless that barename was the only reference to that "previous object", in which case the latter may be destroyed -- but that's obviously not the case here, since `self` is a reference to the same objects as `my_obj` and so `self` cannot be the *only* reference to it).

**Edit**:

You refer to needing to initialize the newly-re-classed object -- that's easy:

```
self.__dict__.clear()
self.__class__ = Butterfly
self.__init__(whatever, you, want)
```

But then in a comment you mention needing to "back up the attributes" -- I don't know what exactly you mean, or why that would at all differ from your "dream case" of assigning directly to `self` (which would of course blow the attributes away, too).  Maybe the idea is that (some of) the arguments to `__init__` need to be attributes of `self`?  Then, for example, you could code it like:

```
d, self.__dict__ = self.__dict__, {}
self.__class__ = Butterfly
self.__init__(d['whatever'], d['you'], d['want'])
```

Comment: I don't want to just reclassify the object, I want to instantiate an entirely new object.  In my actual problem, grow_up() would be passing arguments (based on self attributes) to the Butterfly constructor.

Comment: There is **no** way in Python to have `self` (a barename, passed as an argument) be affected "in the caller" by barename assignments done in any method or function.  You can call `self.__init__` after you assign the `__class__` (which is emphatically **NOT** a "rename" of anything!!!) with whatever arguments you want -- you can even call `self.__dict__.clear()` before then to make sure you have no "stray" state from the previous "incarnation" left around -- but you cannot change the **identity** of the object -- `id(my_obj)` **will** be identical before and after the call, **whatever** you do.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that variables in Python are names that are *bound* to objects.  Read [section 4.1 of the Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) for more details.  The gist of it is that a method parameter is a name that is bound to the object that is passed in the invocation.

When you *"assign a new value"* to the variable, you are simply binding the local name to a new object.  The object that it originally referred to is unchanged.

When you invoke a mutating method on a variable, the method can change the internal state of the object by using a *qualified name* such as `self.var` which is what [Alex is referring to in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209419/how-do-i-change-out-the-underlying-object-inside-a-method-call/3209423#3209423).  If you rebind `self`, you are not modifying the object.

This is one of the more interesting features of Python.  It is a little different than most other languages in that you really have no way to access the raw object pointer (e.g., `this`) within a method.  The only thing that you have access to is the bound name of the instance.

**Edit:**  I don't know how I managed to forget to answer your actual question, but the answer is certainly that you cannot change the underlying object from within a method call.  My rambling was the *why* part without actually providing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is fundamentally flawed. A caterpillar and butterfly are not different creatures, they are different states **of the same creature**.

```
class Lepidoptera(Insect):

    # Just use strings for states
    CATERPILLAR = "caterpillar"
    BUTTERFLY = "butterfly"

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = Lepidoptera.CATERPILLAR

    def grow_up(self):
        self.state = Lepidoptera.BUTTERFLY

    def status(self):
        """ Override superclass method. """
        print "I am a %s, currently in the state: %s" % (self, self.state)
```

If you needed something more sophisticated, the states should be more sophisticated objects that take extra parameters (or simply let the Lepidoptera class take care of it internally).

You are effectively asking how to change a lepidoptera into a cricket, which cannot happen. This is **why** you cannot find a way to represent this concept in your program (or why it seems so hacky). You've decided to use objects to represent **insects**, but then you actually create classes that represent insect **states**. Then you wonder why you can't model the insect behaviour properly.

Working the other way, if you want classes to represent insect states, then clearly you need other classes to represent to insects themselves, which  would then contain these states and the methods to change them.

In terms of your real problem, it sounds like you're confusing "the thing with the state" with "the state itself".

Comment: My problem was that of python syntax and features, not of program design.  Perhaps I should have used better class names in my example.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex puts it clearly, there is no way to do that strictly. 
And I can't think of a way it such a thing could be desirable. Maybe you need a factory function insetad?  Or different states of the same object?

However, Python being what it is, you can have a "shell" object whose only purpose would be to grant access to an underlyign object. The underlying object could then be modified: while the shell object remains the same,  the underlying object is another one.

One possible implementation is as follows (and I've tried again with an unclean implementation for `__getattribute__` - it can be made better)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Insect(object):
        pass

class Catterpillar(Insect):
    a = "I am a caterpillar"
class Butterfly(Insect):
    a = "I am a butterfly"

class Cocoon(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self._true = Catterpillar(*args, **kw)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            if attr != "_true":
                return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_true"),attr)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr != "_true":
            setattr(self._true, attr, val)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)

    def change(self, *args, **kw):
        self._true = Butterfly(*args, **kw)
```

WIth this you can get stuff like:

```
>>>
>>> a=  Cocoon()
>>> a.a
'I am a caterpillar'
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.Catterpillar'>
>>> a.change()
>>> a.a
'I am a butterfly'
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.Butterfly'>
>>>
```

.
On the change function you can backup whatever attributes you want, and you can exempt other attributes from change in the `__getattribute__` method.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answered my question, thanks!